# Quasi-split tori and algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a perfect field.

Recall that an algebraic torus $T$ over $k$ is called *quasi-split* if there exists some finite étale $k$-algebra $A$ such that
$$T \cong \mathrm{R}_{A/k} \mathbb{G}_m.$$

A reductive group $G$ over $k$ is called *quasi-split* if it contains a Borel subgroup $B$ over $k$.

A priori, I see no reason why these two definitions should be related; Indeed any algebraic torus is quasi-split in the second sense (take $B=T$), but generally not in the first sense. However, I have seen it claimed, or at least implicitly used, in proofs that for *semisimple* $G$, the latter implies the former. Namely:

> > Let $G$ be a semisimple algebraic group over $k$ with a maximal torus $T$. If $G$ is quasi-split, then is $T$ quasi-split? Does the converse hold?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $SU(2, 2)$ over $\mathbf{R}$ is semisimple and quasi-split, but its maximal torus is not.

Comment: If a simply connected semisimple $k$-group $G$ has a Borel subgroup $B$ (defined over $k$), then any maximal torus $T\subset B\subset G$ is quasi-split in your sense.

Comment: It not true, that *any* maximal torus in a quasi-split group is quasi-split in your sense (consider a compact torus in the split group $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ ).

Comment: Yes, thanks. Shortly after asking my question, I realised it was simple to see that the converse won't hold.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi I am puzzled by the apparent contradiction between your comment and my example. (I'm taking $SU(2, 2)$ with the anti-diagonal Hermitian form, so the upper-triangular matrices form a Borel, and the diagonal matrices form a maximal torus, isomorphic to the fibre product of two copies of $\operatorname{Res}_{\mathbf{C}/\mathbf{R}} \mathbf{G}_m$ over their common map to $\mathbf{G}_m$; unless I've missed something obvious, this is not quasisplit.)

Comment: @David Loeffler: The determinant of an element of $U(2,2)$ is in $U(1)$. So, you get a fiber product over $U(1)$ instead of $\mathbf G_m$. The resulting torus is indeed quasi-split.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler: I can explain the proof in terms of coroots (this is the same as Knop writes). Let $\alpha_1^\vee,\alpha_2^\vee,\alpha_3^\vee$ be the simple coroots of $G=SU(2,2)$ with respect to $T$ and $B$. Since $G$ is simply connected, these simple coroots consitute a basis of the cocharacter group of $T$. Since $B$ is defined over $\mathbb{R}$, the complex conjugation permutes the simple coroots. Thus $T\simeq \mathbb{R}^*\times\mathbb{C}^*$, hence it is quasi-split.

Comment: Aargh! Of course you are quite right, I had a feeling something must be wrong with my "counterexample".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A torus $T$ is quasi-split if its character group is a permutation representation for the Galois group. So a counterexample to your question is: let $G$ be the quasi-split group $SO(n+1,n-1)$, $n\ge2$, $k=\mathbb R$. The weight lattice is $\mathbb Z^n$ with Galois action
$$
(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n)\mapsto(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},-x_n)
$$
This is not a permutation module.

On the other hand, the Galois action on $T\subseteq B\subseteq G$ of a quasi-split group is induced by an action on the simple roots. These form a basis if $G$ is of adjoint type. For simply connected groups one can play the same game with fundamental representations. So:

If $G$ is quasi-split, and either simply connected or of adjoint type then the maximal $k$-torus sitting in a $k$-Borel is quasi-split.

I have the suspicion that the two notions of "quasi-splitness" developed independently.

Comment: This is great, thanks. Indeed in my case $G$ is adjoint. Do you know a precise reference in the literature where this result is proved?

Comment: @David Loeffler: I edited the answer such that the statement is less misleading.

Comment: @DanielLoughran: The assertion about *simply connected* groups was known to Harder, see Bericht über neuere Resultate, 1968, the last lemma. He writes: Dieses Lemma ist leicht verifiziert. I remember Colliot-Thélène wrote down the proof in one of his papers. I have never seen the assertion about *adjoint* groups in the literature, but Knop's answer contains a proof! The point is that for an adjoint group the simple *roots* constitute a basis (of the character group), and for a simply connected group the simple *coroots* constitute a basis (of the cocharacter group).

Comment: Sansuc calls such tori "quasi-trivial" rather than "quasi-split".

Comment: I followed up Borovoi's reference. In "Bericht..." Harder actually refers to his paper (http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002086735&physid=PHYS_0187) Halbeinfache Gruppenringe über Dedekindringen and sure enough there it is for adjoint groups as well: See remark (2) on page 173. By the way, Harder calls these tori "almost trivial".

Comment: Perhaps the term "quasi-split" (or "quasi-trivial") for tori arose because according to Shapiro's Lemma (and Hilbert 90) $H^1(F,R_{L/F}\mathbf{G}_m) = H^1(L,\mathbf{G}_m) = 1$ -- i.e. "the first galois cohomology group of a quasi-split torus is the same (i.e. is trivial) as that for a split torus".

Comment: This fact for adjoint and simply connected cases was known prior to Harder's paper; e.g., it is Prop. 3.13 Exp. XXIV of SGA3 (expressing the maximal torus in a Borel subgroup as the Weil restriction of ${\rm{GL}}_1$ over the finite etale cover given by the "scheme of Dynkin diagrams").  The setup there may seem forbiddingly general, but the method of proof is exactly the same permutation argument.  This fact must have been known to Borel, Tits, Steinberg, et al. prior to SGA3, but at least SGA3 provides an earlier reference. The terminology "quasi-split" for such tori is bad; please avoid it.

Comment: @nfdc23.  What is a better term than "quasi-split" for tori?  That is an honest question; I do not know what is a good term.  Would "permutation torus" be a better term?

Comment: @JasonStarr: "Induced torus".

Comment: @JasonStarr: Borovoi gave the response I would have given. The motivation for this alternative terminology is that the geometric character lattice of the Weil restriction of a torus through a finite separable extension of fields is the induced representation (for absolute Galois groups) of the geometric character lattice of the given torus. For a hands-on proof of that (natural) identification, see the proof of Theorem 2.4(a) in Chapter II of Oesterle's 1984 Inventiones paper "Nombres de Tamagawa...".